# outsystems iFrame issue

Tags: java, outsystems

I'm using outsystems and I am trying to get the app to run in their browser but something about iFrame popped up. How do I disable iFrame so that the app can run in the browser?

"Your app requires native access to a Local Storage database that is not available in your browser while using an iframe.
Please test your app in your mobile device or use Google Chrome"[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjp55.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
On **Safari Options** go to **Advanced > Experimental Features** and at the end t**urn off** the option that say **Disable Web SQL**.